Sqlite SELECT last_insert_rowid() as lastId returns 0
In a Ionic 7/Angular 18 project I need to save Ventas (sales) and the products belonging to that sale in an SQLite database so I save the venta and then the products.
As I need the idventa to have the reference in products I use SELECT last_insert_rowid() as lastId but always get 0. ventas and productos_ventas are recorded in the database just with the issue that idventa in productos_venta table is 0:
{
    "name": "ventas",
    "schema": [
        { "column": "idventa", "value": "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" },
        { "column": "idcliente", "value": "INTEGER NOT NULL" },
        { "column": "idusuario", "value": "INTEGER" },
        { "column": "monto_total", "value": "REAL" },
        { "column": "fecha", "value": "TEXT NOT NULL" }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "productos_ventas",
    "schema": [
        { "column": "idproducto_venta", "value": "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" },
        { "column": "idproducto", "value": "INTEGER NOT NULL" },
        { "column": "idventa", "value": "INTEGER NOT NULL" },
        { "column": "cantidad", "value": "INTEGER NOT NULL" },
        { "column": "precio", "value": "REAL NOT NULL" },
        { "column": "monto", "value": "REAL" }
    ]
}

The code:
async saveVentaL(
    venta: { idcliente: number, idusuario: number, monto_total: number, fecha: string },
    productos_ventas: { idproducto: number, cantidad: number, precio: number, monto: number }[]
): Promise<{ ventaId: number; changes: capSQLiteChanges }> {
    console.log("Starting to save venta locally: ", venta, productos_ventas);

    const ventaSql = 'INSERT INTO ventas (idcliente, idusuario, monto_total, fecha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    const productosVentasSql = 'INSERT INTO productos_ventas (idventa, idproducto, cantidad, precio, monto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
    const dbName = await this.getDbName();

    // Insert venta
    const ventaChanges: capSQLiteChanges = await CapacitorSQLite.run({
        database: dbName,
        statement: ventaSql,
        values: [venta.idcliente, venta.idusuario, venta.monto_total, venta.fecha]
    });

    if (this.isWeb) {
        await CapacitorSQLite.saveToStore({ database: dbName });
    }

    const ventaId = await this.queryLastInsertRowId();
    console.log("Venta ID: ", ventaId);

    // Prepare statements for productos_ventas
    const statements: any[] = productos_ventas.map(pv => ({
        statement: productosVentasSql,
        values: [ventaId, pv.idproducto, pv.cantidad, pv.precio, pv.monto]
    }));

// Insert productos_ventas
const productosVentasChanges: capSQLiteChanges = await CapacitorSQLite.executeSet({
    database: dbName,
    set: statements
});

if (this.isWeb) {
    await CapacitorSQLite.saveToStore({ database: dbName });
}

console.log("Changes after saving productos_ventas locally: ", productosVentasChanges);
return { ventaId, changes: productosVentasChanges };
}

private async queryLastInsertRowId(): Promise<number> {
    const dbName = await this.getDbName();
    const sql = 'SELECT last_insert_rowid() as lastId';
    return CapacitorSQLite.query({
        database: dbName,
        statement: sql,
        values: [],
    }).then((response: capSQLiteValues) => {
        const lastId = response.values?.[0]?.lastId;
        if (lastId !== undefined) {
            return lastId;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to retrieve last insert row ID.');
        }
    });
}

Starting to save venta locally:
{idcliente: 1, idusuario: 2, monto_total: 240, fecha: '2024-07-09T07:32:15.541Z'} [{…}]
sqlite.service.ts:279
Venta ID:  0
sqlite.service.ts:297
Changes after saving productos_ventas locally:  {changes: {…}}
venta.page.ts:96
Venta saved locally successfully: {ventaId: 0, changes: {…}}
venta.page.ts:102
idventa is undefined. Full response: {ventaId: 0, changes: {…}}changes: {changes:    {…}}ventaId: 0[[Prototype]]: Object
(anonymous) @ venta.page.ts:102
venta.page.ts:107
Venta save operation completed.


Use RETURNING

The promise will not wait for the return, so the code inside then block (asynchronous) will execute after the code below the then block (synchronous). So you should use await to wait for the response and then return it, without the then block.
To learn more about synchronous/asynchronous, I recommend this What is event loop, which helped me out to learn.
private async queryLastInsertRowId(): Promise<number> {
    const dbName = await this.getDbName();
    const sql = 'SELECT last_insert_rowid() as lastId';
    const response: capSQLiteValues = await CapacitorSQLite.query({
        database: dbName,
        statement: sql,
        values: [],
    });
    const lastId = response.values?.[0]?.lastId;
    if (lastId !== undefined) {
        return lastId;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Failed to retrieve last insert row ID.');
    }
}


I found the problem I had to change       // Retrieve the last insert row ID
const ventaId = ventaChanges.changes.lastId;
console.log("Venta ID: ", ventaId);

https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/blob/master/docs/API.md
Changes
Prop Type Description
changes number the number of changes from an execute or run command
lastId number the lastId created from a run command
values any[] values when RETURNING
